# Is it possible to limit the number of concurrent requests to Apache and buffer the excess requests (instead of returning 503)?

Tags: apache-2.4, php-fpm, 503-error

I have a website served by Apache 2.4 with PHP-FPM. Some pages take a few seconds to be generated.
From time to time, some bot or crawler tries to download lots of these pages at once, PHP processes are spawned for all of the requests and the server becomes very slow because it runs out of memory.

I can limit the number of PHP processes or the number of concurrent connections (and even the number of concurrent connections from a single IP with mod_qos), but then further requests (or at least further requests from that IP) immediately get a 503 result. Is it possible to keep the excess requests in a backlog and process them when the previous requests have finished?

Answer (score -2):

Install a Nginx as a reverse proxy and apply rate limiting there, as per this manual: https://www.nginx.com/blog/rate-limiting-nginx/

I don't want to copy all the features depicted on that page, there are many and you better read that yourself. That's official blog page, so it is unlikely it'll go.